# Ray and square/rectangle intersection in 3D

Tags: python, graphics, geometry, intersection

I am making a game and am looking for a ray intersection onto a square or a rectangle only in 3D space. I have searched the web and found many solutions but nothing I can understand have a line and line segment intersection script in 2D but I can't figure out have to make it 3D.

It is not important from what side it intersect the square or rectangle but it must be able to retrieve the point of intersection vector so that later can be tested for distance to se if it occurred before or after other intersections on the same ray intersection.

Any examples in python or other similar scripting languages will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: Don't know have to modify the 2D to show an example but made a new and posting both.

```
// This is the example it test a ray onto a plane then look to se if that point is in the rectangle and saves it to test for distance later
list Faces; // Triangle faces
list Points;

vector FindPoint(){
    // Calculate the point of intersection onto the plane and returns it
    // If it can intersect
    // Else return ZERO_VECTOR
}

integer point-in-quadrilateral(){
    // Return 1 if the point is in the rectangular on the plane
    // Else return 0
}

default{
    state_entry(){
        integer n = (Faces != []); // Return number of elements
        integer x = 0;
        while(x < n){
            vector intersection = FindPoint( FromList(Faces, x) ); // Take out a element and runs it trough the function
            if(intersection != ZERO_VECTOR){
                integer test = point-in-quadrilateral( FromList(Faces,     x) ); // Find out if the point is in rectangular
                if(test == 1){ // If so
                    Points += intersection; // Save the point
                }
            }
            ++x;
        }

        float first; // The distance to the box intersection
        integer l = (Points != []);
        integer d;
        while(d < l){
            if(Dist( FromList(Points, d) ) < first) // If the new distance is less then first
                return 0; // Then end script
            ++d;
        }
    }
}

// This is the 2D version
vector lineIntersection(vector one, vector two, vector three, vector four){
float bx = two.x - one.x;
float by = two.y - one.y;
float dx = four.x - three.x;
float dy = four.y - three.y; 
float b_dot_d_perp = bx*dy - by*dx;
if(b_dot_d_perp == 0.0) {
    return ZERO_VECTOR;
}
float cx = three.x-one.x; 
float cy = three.y-one.y;
float t = (cx*dy - cy*dx) / b_dot_d_perp; 
if(LineSeg){ //if true tests for line segment
    if((t < 0.0) || (t > 1.0)){
        return ZERO_VECTOR;
    }
    float u = (cx * by - cy * bx) / b_dot_d_perp;
    if((u < 0.0) || (u > 1.0)) {
        return ZERO_VECTOR;
    }
}

return <one.x+t*bx, one.y+t*by, 0.0>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a vector equation for a line in R3, then solve for the intersection of that line in the plane of the rectangle that you are testing it against. After that, it's simple enough to test if that point of solution lies within the bounds.

the parameter t of the solution can be found with:

```
t = (a * (x0 - rx) + b * (y0 - ry) + c * (x0 - rz)) / (a * vx + b * vy + c * vz)
```

where:

```
a(x - x0) + b(y - y0) + c(z - z0) = 0
```

is the equation of the plane that your rectangle lies on

and:

```
<x, y, z> = <rx + vx * t, ry + vy * t, rz + vz * t>
```

is the vector equation of the line in question.

note that:

```
<rx, ry, rz>
```

is the initial point of the vector equation, and

```
<vx, vy, vz>
```

is the direction vector of the above equation

After that, plugging the parameter t into your vector equation will give you the point to test for distance.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the respons. Can you explane some part of it? Are the "x0 y0 z0" the equalizer to its equal x, y and z to make the second equation equal to zero? if so how to calculate the value for each of them?

Comment: Essentially, yes. x0, y0, and z0 are the values of SOME point (it can be any point) that lies on the same plane as your rectangle. As for x, y, and z within that equation, you would plug in the values for the line equation listed above (r_ + v_ * t). Can you be more specific about how you plan on writing the code? Maybe an example of the 2d version you said you were able to work out? I might be able to explain better that way.

Comment: Have edited the main post for an exaple and the 2D version. Have done some more founding out and are woundring if the a, b and c are the unit vector of the plane? and are the x0, y0, and z0 the line equation? have run a multiple combinations but can geat it to equal zero.

Comment: I edited the post to include an image for clarification. Anyway, the second equation I gave is not important. What you really want is to plug the values into the first equation to get the parameter "t". After that you would plug the "t" into the vector equation for the line (the ray you are tracing -- that's the third equation btw).

Answer (score 17):

The solution is very easy when you define a ray with a point(= vector) and a direction vector, and the rectangle with a point(= vector) and two vectors representing the sides.

Suppose the ray is defined as `R0 + t * D`, where `R0` is the origin of the ray, `D` is an unit vector representing its direction and `t` is its length.

The rectangle can be represented with a corner point `P0`, and two vectors `S1` and `S2` which should represent the sides (their length being equal to the length of the sides). You will need another vector `N` normal to its surface, which is equal to the unit vector along the cross product of `S1` and `S2`.

Now, assume the ray intersects the rect at `P`. Then, the direction of the ray, `D` must make a nonzero angle with the normal `N`. This can be verified by checking `D.N < 0`.

To find the intersection point, assume `P = R0 + a * D` (the point must be on the ray). You need to find the value of `a` now. Find the vector `P0P`. This must be perpendicular to `N`, which means `P0P.N = 0` which reduces to `a = ((P0 - R0).N) / (D.N)`.

Now you need to check if the point is inside the rect or not. To do this, take projection `Q1` of `P0P` along `S1` and `Q2` of `P0P` along `S2`. The condition for the point being inside is then `0 <= length(Q1) <= length(S1)` and `0 <= length(Q2) <= length(S2)`.

This method is appropriate for any type of parallelograms, not only for rectangles. [Update: it looks like this statement about parallelograms created some confusions. In case of parallelograms (which also includes rectangles), the projection on one side should be taken along the other side, not just as a perpendicular line on it (quoting from the last paragraph: "take projection `Q1` of `P0P` along `S1` and `Q2` of `P0P` along `S2`"). It is like working with a coordinate system where the axes are not perpendicular to each other.]

Comment: From my five minute drawing, using the ending condition(s) for the projections `Q1` and `Q2` does not work with all points in all parallelograms. What am I missing?

Comment: The mentioned drawing, with an extra `P0` instead of a `P`: http://imgur.com/a/Dt6ZvIV

Comment: You take a big leap from `P0P.N = 0` to `a = ((P0 - R).N) / (D.N)`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: `P0P` can be written as `R0P - R0P0` (it comes from the triangle `R0P0P`). `R0P` is `P - R0 = a * D` and `R0P0 = P0 - R0`. Combining all these gives you the expression for `a`.

Comment: One more thing. If `a < 0` there is no intersection

Comment: You said this is good "for any type of parallelograms", but I am finding that is not exactly true. I tried giving the obtuse corner of a rhombus and its sides to this algorithm, and it did not detect some intersections. It is starting to look to me like taking the projections screws things up if you want to capture the exact area of a non-rectangular parallelogram.

Comment: @SufianLatif. I'm a bit confused about `P0P`. Based on your comment doesn't `R0` get canceled out? So `P0P = P - P0 = a * D + RO - P0`. In other words, `P0P` is just the vector pointing from `P0` (corner of rectangle) to `P` (ray's intersection with plane).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the square/rectangle in 3D is aligned with the coordinate axes or not.
Assuming the 3D rectangle *R* is oriented arbitrarily in space, here is one method.
First interesect your ray *r* with the plane containing *R*.  This can be accomplished by requiring a
scale factor *s* to multiply *r* and place it on the plane of *R*, and solving for *s*.  This gives you a point *p* on the plane.  Now project the plane, and *R* and *p*, on to one of the coordinate
planes {*xy*, *yz*, *zx*}.  You only have to avoid projecting perpendicular to the normal vector to the plane, which is always possible.  And then solve the point-in-quadrilateral problem in the plane of projection.

Before beginning, check if your line segment lies in the 3D plane of *R*, and if so, handle that separately.

Comment: Thanks for respons. The squares and rectangles can be rotated any way in 3D. So if i understand it correctly the part you write 'First interesect your ray r with the plane containing R. This can be accomplished by requiring a scale factor s to multiply r and place it on the plane of R, and solving for s' is the solution given by Joel Carnett then i use the point of intersection vector given from that and solve it with point-in-quadrilateral to find if it is inside the boundaries.

Comment: Yes, you understand it.  I apparently answered at too high a level, but Joel is essentially articulating in equations what I described in prose.