# Ray/Rectangle intersection in 3D space

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection, raytracing

Im having trouble with calculating whether line/ray intersects a rectangle (thats on a plane) in 3d space.

I have searched and the only thing I found was [Ray and square/rectangle intersection in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812073/ray-and-square-rectangle-intersection-in-3d) but I just cant quite understand the last steps and how to apply it for my system.

So I have a Ray

```
struct Ray
{
  Vector3 m_startPoint;  // P0
  Vector3 m_direction;   // Direction Unit Vector
  float m_length;         // Ray length
};
```

and I have a quad defined by

```
struct Quad
{
    Vector3 p1;    
    Vector3 p2;
    Vector3 p3;
    Vector3 p4;
    Vector3 normal;
}
```

What I first did was calculate whether the ray would ever hit the plane using the dot product

```
float dotProd = D3DXVec3Dot(&ray.m_direction, &quad.normal);

if (dotProd < 0)     // if <0 ray will travel into the plane
{
    // Get the point of intersection
    float distToIntersection
    //Vector3D intersectPoint = ray.m_startPoint + (distToIntersection * ray.m_direction);

    // Check whether the point of intersection is within the bounds of the Quad
}
```

And this is where I get stuck...

I know its been answered before but I can't make it work for my system so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I'm not sure your `Quad` struct fully defines a quad. Even if I collapse them down to the plane, how do I know e.g. whether (0, 0) and (1, 1) defines a zero-height quad with (1, 1) being a basis vector or a 1x1 quad with (0, 1) and (1, 0) being basis vectors, or any other quad entirely? Are you assuming axis alignment?

Comment: @Tommy  Hi,  hmmm, possibly.  I will adjust the Quad definition so that it's easier to work with anyway.

Comment: I suggest that you first perform a [ray-plane intersection](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm) computation, and then, once you have the point of intersection on the plane, decide if it is inside or outside the rectangle (by projecting to 2D).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thats down the lines of what I wanted to do, Could you show me the method of projecting onto 2D?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> "Could you show me the method of projecting onto 2D?"

Maybe this will help. Note the projection of a rectangle is a convex quadrilateral (not generally a rectangle), so you will need four `LeftOf( )` tests to verify inclusion
of the projected point.

---

[image: RectProjection]

---

You can find `LeftOf( )` in many place, including [this textbook](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html).

Don't forget to test if the rectangle lies in a plane orthogonal to the *xy*-plane, in which case you should project to either the *xz*- or the *yz*-plane.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing dotProd test just tells you whether the direction of your ray is along the normal or away from it.

What you probably want to do is:

1. get distance of start point and of end point from plane;
2. if both distances have the same sign then stop — there's no intersection;
3. otherwise calculate the intersection point — if start distance is `s` and end distance is `e` then it's necessarily at the point `s / (s - e)` along the line;
4. perform a point-in-rectangle test on the point: if its x is in the x range of the box and its y is in the y range of the box then it's inside and the ray strikes the rectangle. Otherwise it does not.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by start point and end point? Do you mean the beginning of the Ray and the end or the Ray?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was unclear. So start point is literally `m_startPoint`. End point is `m_startPoint + m_length * m_direction` (assuming appropriate operators and that direction is of unit length).