# How to find a complementary parallelogram

Tags: python, matlab, geometry, intersection, geometry-surface

On https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862483/4918319, an algorithm is put forward with which to determine whether a ray in 3-space goes through a given rectangle, if we specify the ray by two vectors (one specifying the origin of the ray and the other its direction) and the rectangle by three vectors (one specifying the location of one corner and the other two giving the relative positions of the two corners adjacent to that one).

The author then asserts that this algorithm is not limited to squares & rectangles, but also works for any parallelogram. However, while that initially appears to be true, and works to a limited extent, the fact is that, because projection is used, which involves moving a point onto a line by a course perpendicular to the line, it does not work, as it is, for just any parallelogram.

However, it appears that every parallelogram, once you have selected a corner, has one complementary parallelogram. Each parallelogram covers the area which that algorithm would attribute to its complement, and vice versa. For example, if you draw a rhombus and select an obtuse corner of it, and then shade the area of the paper that projects to each of the two sides which that corner joins, the shaded areas will overlap to form another rhombus, with one acute corner at the point which you selected. Then, if you draw the acute rhombus and then shade the areas of the paper which project to the sides adjacent to the originally selected corner, the shaded area will form the same shape, size, and orientation as your original rhombus.

The question remains, how to derive the complement of a parallelogram once you know the three vectors which define the first?

Comment: I haven't read the linked  post, but can't you apply a coordinate transformation to turn the parallelogram into a rectangle? For that, it suffices to apply an angular shift to one of two coordinate axes. Then use the linked algorithm. I think that the ray goes through the parallelogram if and only if the transformed ray goes through the rectangle

Comment: If my suggestion above doesn't work, or if you want to follow the approach outlined in your question, please clarify this part: _However, it appears that every parallelogram, once you have selected a corner, has one complementary parallelogram._. How do you define the complementary parallelogram?

Comment: @LuisMendo If you could specify what type of transform to apply to which variables, that would certainly be a valid answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I initially thought this was a 2D problem. I don't have time to ellaborate or check in 3D, but here's the idea in case it helps you find a full solution:

Comment: (1) Apply a 3D rotation of the coordinate axes so that the new _x_ axis is aligned with one of the parallelogram directions. (2) Apply a [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) to make the _y_ axis aligned with the other parallelogram direction. Treating the new axes as if they were orthogonal, the parallelogram is now a rectangle parallel to the _xy_ plane, which makes the problem easy. The "going through" property is clearly preserved by (1), and I _think_ it is also preserved by (2)

Comment: You should avoid to use your own vaguely defined term 'complementary parallelogram'. Anyway, you don't need to struggle with parallelograms. There is a generic algorithm to test if a point is inside a closed polygon. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for example.

Comment: @Luis Mendo, FYI, the OP is solving a 2D problem. He is solving the problem of whether the intersection point between a ray and the plane containing a parallelogram is inside the parallelogram, or not. Your suggestion of using an affine(shear) transformation is one of good solution.